# unable to pass a List from controller to view in play framework

Tags: playframework-2.0

I'll pass a list of BSONDocument to html file. The error is `too many arguments for method apply: ()play.api.templates.HtmlFormat.Appendable in object list`.

```
@{ import reactivemongo.bson._}
@(list: List[BSONDocument])


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
@list.map(elem=> {
    <p>
        @{elem}
    </p>
   })
</body>
</html>
```

I am calling the view from controller as follows

```
findFutureList.map((list:List[BSONDocument]) => {
Logger.debug("list count:"+list.length)
Ok(views.html.list(list)) 
 })
```

The code works if I pass a List[String] instead of List[BSONDocument]. I think the issue is with importing reactive library in the view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first line must be argument line. Import must be after it, so you can fix it with something like:

```
@(list: List[reactivemongo.bson.BSONDocument])
```

Or

```
@(list: List[reactivemongo.bson.BSONDocument])
@{ import reactivemongo.bson._}
```

Comment: What would I do without you Andriy!